# CSS styling issue for replicating logo

Tags: css

I'm trying to replicate this design for my logo but struggling with the CSS. So far I have managed to write the code below but am struggling to create the stacked text for growth hacker and entrepreneur. If you have any guidance it would be much appreciated.

[image]

```
<a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-fix" href="<?php echo site_url('/') ?>">Elliott Davidson | <span class="logo-growth-hacker">Growth Hacker</span><br><span class="logo-entrepreneur">Entrepreneur</span></a>

.navbar-brand
  font-weight: bold
  font-size: 1rem
  text-transform: uppercase
  color: $light-grey
  padding: 30px 30px 30px 0px

.navbar-default .navbar-brand
  color: $light-grey

a.navbar-brand.navbar-brand-fix

  span.logo-growth-hacker
    font-weight: 200
    font-size: 0.5em
    text-transform: none
    vertical-align: text-top

  span.logo-entrepreneur
    font-weight: 200
    font-size: 0.5em
    text-transform: none
    margin-top: -18px
    float: inherit
    margin-left: 182px
    padding-top: 5px
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. Create a couple of flex columns using the row layout and style accordingly.

```css
a {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #666, #666 50%, #444 50%, #444);
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.col {
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  padding: 0 0 0 1rem;
  margin: 0 0 0 1rem;
  font-size: .6rem;
}
a:hover .col { border-color: red; }
```

```html
<a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-fix" href="<?php echo site_url('/') ?>">
  <span class="name">Elliott Davidson</span>
  <span class="col">
    Growth Hacker<br>
    Entrepreneur
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: the only one thing I have noticed is the the border left dosen't change when I add a hover state to that class. I have to specifically hover over the border element instead of the whole logo. Do you understand?

Comment: what's your end goal with the hover/border? what do you want to hover over and what do you want to happen with the border?

Comment: when I hover over any of the logo the border colour changes to. Currently I have to hover right on top of the border get get that element to get it to change.

Comment: Thanks that was it cant believe it was that basic.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this may get you started :-)

```css
.logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.logo > * {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.title > * {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <div class="name">
    Elliott Davidson
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <div class="funText">
      Growth Hacker
    </div>
    <div class="position">
      Entrepreneur
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That said, you may just be better off just using an SVG for something very logo centric like this. Still written in code, but more vector centric instead of block centric.

Comment: I appreciate the response and this gives we some good guidance, thanks.